# How can I sort each column in a user input 3x3 2d array from smallest to largest? in JAVA language

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multiple-columns

> Ive looked at other questions/answers on this website. however none
>   seem to be solving this problem specifically. This is my code so far but I am > getting a
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3    at > > ColumnSorting.sortColumns(ColumnSorting.java:13)     at                        > > TestColumnSorting.main(TestColumnSorting.java:19)
>   error when i run it.

```
public static int[][] sortColumns(int[][] matrix)
       {
          int tmp = 0;
          int ct = 0;
          for(int column = 0; column < matrix[ct].length; column++)
          {
             for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) 
             {
                for (int i = row+1; i < matrix.length; i++) 
                {
                   if(matrix[row][column] > matrix[i][column])
                   {
                      tmp = matrix[row][column];
                      matrix[row][column] = matrix[i][column];
                      matrix[i][column] = tmp ;
                   }
                }
             }
             ct++;
          }
       return matrix;
```

Comment: You should've written which language you're working in. Well, now you just given a hint that it should be Java, but just saying.

Comment: Sorry! Will update question.

Comment: How about iterating over columns and doing a 1D sort on each column?

Comment: how does that differ from what im doing here? unless i just wrote it wrong, i believed that this code goes to each column {0-3} and then goes to each row and determines which value is larger, and then swaps it if is?

Comment: Because you're going above 2 in one of the columns

Comment: which line? the only line that affects which column im on is the first for loop, which shouldnt go past the amount of columns that exist in the array

Comment: @BroStevens I'm not sure which line because I do not know the bounds of the array nor do I have line numbers. When in doubt, change the matrix length to `length - 1`

Comment: Alright i just tried that. Like i said im doing a 3x3 array. I jsut entered {3,2,4}.{4,2,1},{1,5,3} and it sorted the 1st column, but did not sort the third column. Why would it do that? I just ran it using different numbers. It is in fact sorting the first 2 columns correctly and then ignoring the third column.

Comment: What happens when the second loop has `row = matrix.length - 1` and, you hit `for (i = row+1;...`, and then access `matrix[i][column]`? That, I think, is your problem...

Comment: well i thought the previous comment was referring to column = matrix[ct].length-1. not row. Either way that doesnt affect the output im getting. Somehow, my code is failing to get to the third column. or it is failing to sort that third column properly. And that is where im getting confused, since an algorithim does the same thing over and over, why would it work 2 times in a row and not a third. unless i am missing something happening in my code that is being changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`

You're getting this error because at the end of your for loops when you do `ct++` you will eventually get `ct=3`. Since array indexing starts at 0, your 3x3 column indices will go from 0-2. So when `ct=3` and you do `matrix[ct].length` you will get an array out of bounds error.

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an answer

Comment: ahhh okay that makes sense. so would i just make an if statement right below my ct++ that says if it equals 3. break?

Comment: @CupofJava i would have commented but I don't have the Rep to comment on other people's answers/posts...

Comment: @BroStevens yes having some kind of check to make sure you dont increment too far would work.

Comment: im going insane now. the only i have changed this entire time would be the break statemnt for ct and the addition of the matrix[ct],.length-1. and now my code has started to only sort the 2nd column and ignores the 1st and third.

Comment: You are probably getting another index out of bounds in your `i = row+1` for loop. Have you tried using a debugger or using print statements to try and debug your code to see what exactly your variable values are at each step?

Comment: I figured it out GUYS. Thanks for all the help. You guys are all awesome!

Comment: @BroStevens If your issue is resolved, you should have accepted/upvoted an answer. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."